# FetchXML table issue

Tags: sql, fetchxml

I have a table A named `PWD_WARE` and Table named `PWD_Company`.

I can display with left join the table `PWD_WARE` and table `PWD_Company` as following

[Joined PWD_Company and PWD_WARE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POp79.jpg)

| PWD_Company | PWD_WARE |
| --- | --- |
| A | 78 |
| A | compu |
| A | zigt |
| A | utm |

My question, is there anyway to display `PWD_Company` "A" one time like following

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh62b.jpg)

| PWD_Company | PWD_WARE |
| --- | --- |
| A | 78,compu,zigt,utm |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO, this is not a provided function in *FetchXML* and even in many SQL RDBMS that do support it, it is a new or emerging feature.

Traditionally we would support this request through your business logic or a custom API. It is generally not the role of the database engine to format your data into the precise form that you want to present to the user. Joining a list of values like this into a single *string* loses information so this type of logic is better suited to your service or presentation layers.

- use the right tool for the right job.